# Linked List with random integers C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have an assignment to create a linked list. I have to create a "Node" class that is templated to hold any type of data item and a pointer to another Node. Create a linked list  class that will have "add" and display methods. Create a "main" program that adds 20 integers to the list in a loop and displays all the data in the list with a single call to the display method. ie. don't use a loop for the "display" method.

The problem I am having is that when I run the program, the window appears and nothing prints out to the screen. I run the debugger and it shows no errors.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream> 
#include "time.h"
using namespace std; 


template <typename T> 
class Node
{

public: 
    T data; 
    Node* next; 

    Node(int x, Node* addr) {
        data = x; 
        next = addr; 
    }
};


template <typename T> 
class linklist
{
private: 
    Node<T>* first; 
public: 
    linklist()
    {
        first = NULL;
    }
    void addItem(T d); 
    void display();
};


template <typename T> 
void linklist<T>::addItem(T d)
{
    Node<T> *newNode = new Node<T>; 
    newNode->data = d; 

    newNode->next = first; 
    first = newNode; 
}


template <typename T> 
void linklist<T> ::display()
{
    Node<T>* current = first; 
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        cout << current->data << endl; 
        current = current->next; 
    }
}

using namespace std; 

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    linklist<int> intList;

    srand(time(NULL)); 


    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) 
    {
        int random = rand()%100; 
    }
    intList.display(); 
    cin.ignore(); 

    return 0;
};
```

Comment: I do not see where you add items to a list

Answer (score 0):

You haven't called your addItem function that you created to add items in the list.
As the list is empty it will not display anything on the screen. While generating a random number call the addItem method to add items in the list.